# How to disable browsersync in Aurelia application?

Tags: javascript, aurelia, browser-sync

I created an Aurelia application using aurelia-cli.
I need to disable the browsersync option and also the notifications generated by it. Like "Connected to browser sync" Like that.
Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build your application for production, it will not include Browser Sync.

Instead of the normal

```
> au run --watch
```

You'll use

```
> au build --env prod
```

After that, you'll need to serve up your application through a traditional web server.  If you've correctly bundled it, you'll only need index.html and your scripts folder.

Answer (score 0):

just as a dev side note:

browsersync options are available at `localhost:3001` (unless you changed default port)

there you can do things like turn off mirroring clicks and scrolls in all instances of your locally running app (useful when you would like to open two or more different routes in your local app in multiple tabs/browsers) or monitor history of all routes you have visited in your local app.

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable the ghost mode in `aurelia_project/tasks/run.js`.

Just add `ghostMode: false` to the browserSync configuration.

```
let serve = gulp.series(
  build,
  done => {
    browserSync({
      online: false,
      open: false,
      port: 9000,
      logLevel: 'silent',
      ghostMode: false,
      server: {
        baseDir: ['.'],
        middleware: [historyApiFallback(), function(req, res, next) {
          res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
          next();
        }]
      }
    }, function(err, bs) {
      let urls = bs.options.get('urls').toJS();
      log(`Application Available At: ${urls.local}`);
      log(`BrowserSync Available At: ${urls.ui}`);
      done();
    });
  }
);
```

This disables the synchronization of interaction events between browsers. At least for me, this is often the most annoying part.